# Непонятная опечатка

Tags: javascript

Весь мозг себе сломал, но не понимаю где ошибка. На 6 строку ругается `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'`:

```
const getInstagramPosts = async user => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://www.instagram.com/${user}/?__a=1`);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges.map(edge => {
        image: edge.node.display_url,
        text: edge.node.edge_media_to_caption.edges[0].node.text,
    });
};
```

Это как с сусликом. Вы видите тут ошибку? Вот и я нет, а она есть...

Comment: Вы чем-то собираете проект? Покажите выхлоп этого куска

Comment: @Ghost ничем. Я просто в браузере через devtools тестирую. Можете также открыть и вставить - сразу ошибку дает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const getInstagramPosts = async user => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://www.instagram.com/${user}/?__a=1`);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges.map(edge => ({
        image: edge.node.display_url,
        text: edge.node.edge_media_to_caption.edges[0].node.text,
    }));
};
```

Это происходит в струлочной функции: `edge => ...`, если вы хотите создать объект, то его нужно обворачивать в доп. скобки или писать `return`.

`edge => ({...})` или `edge => { return {...}; }`

Comment: Работает, но что было не так? Не уловил разницы... =(

Comment: скобки после стрелки. подразумевали объект, а по факту тело функции.

Comment: Ааа... В скобки обернули словарь?

Comment: Все спасибо. Чет я тупанул.